# What should a secure login script consist of?

Tags: php, security

I am going to write a secure login script and I would like to ask what kind of component it should have.

For now this are the things that came to my mind

Basic

- Using PDO as connector for mysql database
- Securing passwords using SHA512 ( should there be a salt/token involved ? )
- Session and cookie management, trying to avoid the hijack of the session id ( could you provide me with some article about it ? )
- XSS prevention ( could you referee me an article ? )
- SQL Injection prevention sanitation of the input
- Secure connection over https

Registration

- In terms of registration using a reCaptcha

Login

- Count the login attempts and block after 5 failure attempts to prevent from brute force attacks.

After login

- Session timer with destruction ( 12 minutes to loose the session ) with a click to renew the timer [ does anyone has a example of this ? I couldn't find any ]

Are there any more major security hints that I should think off?

Thanks.

Comment: SHA512 is not sufficient for hashing passwords. You need to look at [BCrypt](http://php.net/manual/en/function.password-hash.php).

Comment: Hi, hope this help you with some of your topics:
[Broken_Authentication_and_Session_Management](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/Top_10_2013-A2-Broken_Authentication_and_Session_Management)
and 
[XSS](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/Top_10_2013-A3-Cross-Site_Scripting_(XSS))

Comment: @Imarcelocc Indeed owasp is the source that should have looked

Answer (score 12, accepted):

This is actually a nontrivial problem with a number of issues that need to be considered. Fortunately, a lot of the problems have been solved for you.

- **Password hashing:** Use `password_hash()` and `password_verify()` -- don't use fast hashes like MD5 or SHA1, and also don't roll your own hashing strategy or else you'll find yourself reinventing PBKDF2 sloppily -- `password_hash()` does everything you probably want it to do without having to stress over implementation details. They are adequate; learn these tools well. If you're on PHP < 5.5 use [password_compat](https://github.com/ircmaxell/password_compat)
- **Database API:** PDO is wonderful. Make sure you take full advantage of prepared statements to separate SQL queries from user-supplied data. Otherwise, *doom*.
- **Session Management:** Use the built-in sessions, use HTTPS everywhere with no mixed content, set `"httponly"` and `"secure"` to `true`. Regenerate the session when privilege is escalated (e.g. the user logs in).

  If you want to be paranoid, you can defend against [session fixation attacks](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/Session_fixation) (which aren't really considered practical these days) by setting a [canary](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Animal_sentinel) session variable. Upon page load, if `$_SESSION['canary']` is not defined (or does not match an expected value), destroy the session and treat the user as a new guest.
- **Rate-Limiting:** Add a manual captcha after N login attempts (where N is greater than 1 but still very small).
- **Remember Me:** Perfect example of "seems trivial, really isn't." [Covered in this blog post](https://paragonie.com/blog/2015/05/using-encryption-and-authentication-correctly). If you don't need it, don't implement it.
- [**Account Recovery:** A back-door by any other name](https://paragonie.com/blog/2016/09/untangling-forget-me-knot-secure-account-recovery-made-simple). If you can get away with neglecting this feature, don't implement it at all. Most users are incapable of providing reliably secret answers to security questions.
- **Registration:** You want at least a CAPTCHA here.
- **XSS Prevention:** This is part of any secure web application, not specific to your login form. That said, [HTMLPurifier](http://htmlpurifier.org) is pretty reliable if you want to allow HTML and `htmlentities($input, ENT_QUOTES | ENT_HTML5, 'UTF-8')` is great if you don't want to allow HTML.

This is a subject I am hoping to answer through a series of very thorough blog posts on the [Paragon Initiative Enterprises blog](https://paragonie.com/blog).